# InfluxDB: Empty tags cause field to be 0

Tags: python, database, grafana, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a python worker that sends measurements to influxDB with a `tags` value whenever the value is present. When this `tags` value is not present, I set the `tags` as an empty dictonary.

```py
def emit_measurements(self, values: Dict, tags: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None):

    if tags is None:
        tags = {}
    
    measurement = {
        "measurement": "some_name",
        "tags": tags,
        "time": datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC).isoformat(),
        "fields": values,
    }

    self._influx_client.write_points([measurement])
```

In my influx database I see the correct values for the fields whenever `tags` is not present, but as soon as one event gets emitted with `tags` all fields get turned to 0 and stay like that.

(I'm assuming the measurement table gets corrupted whenever `tags` is present which causes every field value to be 0)

Can this `tags` be optional where some events don't emit it?

Comment: what do you mean by "all fields gets turned to 0"? you mean all the previously stored data is getting updated to 0?

Comment: No, more like subsequent following data is set to 0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tags are optional meta-data for a measurement.

Quoting the [tags documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/glossary/#tag)

> The key-value pair in the InfluxDB data structure that records
> metadata. Tags are an optional part of the data structure, but they
> are useful for storing commonly-queried metadata; tags are indexed so
> queries on tags are performant. Query tip: Compare tags to fields;
> fields are not indexed.